# grouping/counting/matching data in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset containing several columns of different values. Have a look below:

```
X             Y         Z
20:00:00     AAA    ABC123*
20:00:00     BBB    ABC123*
21:00:00     AAA    AEC173
23:00:00     CCC    ABE124
20:00:00     DDD    ABC123*
```

and so on...

Column `X` is containing time, `Y` is three letter code and `Z` is alphanumerical code. 
I would like `R` to highlight me only the occurrences when both `X` and `Z` column values are same, but Y value is different. Such a case would be first two columns that are marked with star and also the last one.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output? In which way you want to present it?

Comment: Kindly consider to upvote or accept the answer when someone has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by grouping X and Z then counts the frequency `n()` of each group then flagged those with `n()>1` and has a Y that is completely unique among them.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% group_by(X,Z) %>% 
        mutate(Flag = ifelse(n()>1 & length(unique(Y))==n(),1,0))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   X, Z [3]
  X        Y     Z       Flag
  <fct>    <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1 20:00:00 AAA   ABC123     1
2 20:00:00 BBB   ABC123     1
3 21:00:00 AAA   AEC173     0
4 23:00:00 CCC   ABE124     0
5 20:00:00 DDD   ABC123     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`: First grouping data by `X` and `Z` and then select the `X,Y` and `distinct(Y)` as follow:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select X,Z,count(distinct Y)>1 as count from df group by X,Z")
```

Outout **(If count is 1 means both X and Z column values are same, but Y value is different):**

```
     X          Z     count
  1 20:00:00  ABC123     1
  2 21:00:00  AEC173     0
  3 23:00:00  ABE124     0
```